# Редирект на сайт банка после заполнение полей обратной связи

Tags: javascript, html

Короче, Товарищи гребцы, вопрос в чем. Делаю сайт, фактически лендинг, но с возможностью оплаты на сайте. Есть форма обратной связи которая шлет данные о пользователе на почту, ее кнопка перенаправляет на страницу "благодарности". Нужно, что бы после ее нажатия отправляла данные на почту, и выполняла переход на страницу оплаты картой (liqpay). Вопрос, как это проще реализовать? Пока две кнопки, или так, или так. Билд самой формы прикреплю. И да, сайт без CMS.

×

```
        <div id="fields"><h3 style="text-align: center">Заполните поля и мы с вами свяжемся!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
            <form id="contact" action="mail/mail.php" method="POST">
                <label for="author">Как вас зовут?</label></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="name" id="author" placeholder="Имя" required>

                <p><label for="email">Номер телефона:</label></p>
                <p><input type="phone" name="email" id="email" placeholder="+380 (__)" required> </p><br>
                <label>Коментарии к заказу:</label>
                <p><textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" id="comment" placeholder="Введите сюда текст сообщения" required></textarea></p>

                <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="go botton-class " id="payment">

                </div>
               </form>

                <form id="form1" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout" >

                    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="eyJwdWJsaWNfa2V5Ijoic2FuZGJveF9pMTg2NTgwNDA2OSIsInZlcnNpb24iOiIzIiwiYWN0aW9uIjoicGF5IiwiYW1vdW50IjoiMyIsImN1cnJlbmN5IjoiVUFIIiwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJ0ZXN0Iiwib3JkZXJfaWQiOiIwMDAxIiwic2VuZGVyX3Bob25lIjoiIn0=" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="PL0qc5zpRLnsuvOFlm3VJWxWNK8=" />
                    <button id="pay" style="border: none !important; display:inline-block !important;text-align: center !important;padding: 7px 20px !important;
color: #fff !important; font-size:16px !important; font-weight: 600 !important; font-family:OpenSans, sans-serif; cursor: pointer !important; border-radius: 2px !important;
background: rgba(122,183,43,1) !important;"onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0.5';" onmouseout="this.style.opacity='1';">
                        <img src="https://static.liqpay.ua/buttons/logo-small.png" name="btn_text"
                             style="margin-right: 7px !important; vertical-align: middle !important;"/>
                        <span style="vertical-align:middle; !important">Оплатить 5 UAH</span>
                    </button>
                </form>



        </div>



    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: А то что вы написали вообще работает?

Comment: Да, а что не так?Работает, но я хочу вызывать событие (два) из одной кнопки. Первая часть поля формы обратной связи. В этом же окне кнопка оплаты. Сигнатура data и sign заданы согласна документации банка через base64_encode, потому наверное и возникают вопросы. Есть какое-то универсальное решение? Есть конечно вариант после оплаты задать result_url, с ссылок на страницу с полями, но это не совсем то.